# Can't perform union in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, union

For some table `t` I'd like to do the following query:

```
select 'X' as "Indicator" from t limit 1
union 
select 'Y' as "Indicator" from t limit 1
```

What I expect:

```
Indicator
X
Y
```

What I get: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "union"`

Why is it so? The column name is the same, in both cases there's only one column. What is wrong?

Comment: The `limit 1` only applies in your query in the very end: `select.. union select ... limit X `

Answer (score 2):

Like this if you want both results

```
(select 'X' as "Indicator" from t limit 1)
union 
(select 'Y' as "Indicator" from t limit 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `LIMIT` goes only in the very end of a statement. You may try to use subqueries ..

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'X' AS indicator FROM t LIMIT 1) j
UNION
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'y' AS indicator FROM t LIMIT 1) j
```

Or with `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'X' AS indicator FROM t FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY) j
UNION
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Y' AS indicator FROM t FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY) j
```

.. even a subquery would do (with a proper `ORDER BY`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (indicator) * FROM (
  SELECT 'X' AS indicator FROM t
  UNION 
  SELECT 'Y' AS indicator FROM t) j
```